# Parsley Checkboxes & Radios not validating in IE only

Tags: parsley.js

Is there something internal with Parsley 2.0.6 that could be causing Internet Explorer's failure to include radio and checkboxes as a `parsleyField.$element` ?

For example, in my ParsleyConfig I have the following:

```
var ParsleyConfig = {
    classHandler: function (parsleyField) {
        var $field = parsleyField.$element;
        // When looped through, contains only text type inputs, 
        // doesn't contain checkbox or radio type inputs. 
        // Happens for IE only.
        console.log($field); 
}
```

I also just discovered it works when I put IE11 in 9 or 10 rendering mode.

Comment: v2.0.6 is quite old.

Comment: I've integrated it as a part of a greater project and have not had the time to update it as it would also require me to update other stuff that uses the parsley config in certain ways that 2.0.6 requires.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out to be purely a IE11 issues, not Parsley.  In Parsley options I had set `:hidden` to not validate. IE11 was reporting my checkbox and radio buttons as hidden because they had a 0 x 0 width/height.   Even though their display was set to block, IE11 only reports them as hidden.